# UITableview shuffle while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiview

I have a `UITableView` with some CustomViews, I am adding everything successfully. But when I scroll the tableview it's shuffle with the the UIImageView those I have added on UIView on runtime.can you please help me out to solve this issue.

Please check my code and give me the right solution.Please prefer only swift3

```
if(tb_LayerType == "layer"){ 
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuitem1", for: indexPath) as! MenuItemMultipleImageTableViewCell

        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        print(indexPath.row)

        cell.lblProductName.text = listSearch[indexPath.row].tb_product_name
        cell.lblProductTopings.text = listSearch[indexPath.row].tb_topping_name
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let productSize = listSearch[indexPath.row].tb_product_size!.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let productAmount = listSearch[indexPath.row].tb_product_amount!.components(separatedBy: ",")
      //  cell.imgView.kf.setImage(with: nil)

        if(productSize[0] == "regular"){
            cell.lblSize.text = "("+" Alm "+")"
            cell.lblPrice.text = productAmount[productSize.index(of: "regular")!]+" kr"
        }else if(productSize[0] == "small"){
            cell.lblSize.text = "("+" Lille "+")"
            cell.lblPrice.text = productAmount[productSize.index(of: "small")!]+" kr"
        }else{
            cell.lblSize.text = "( "+productSize[0].capitalized+" )"
            cell.lblPrice.text = productAmount[0]+" kr"
        }
        extraTopingImages.removeAll()
        extraTopingImages = listSearch[indexPath.row].tb_topping_image!.components(separatedBy: ",")
        for name in extraTopingImages {
            let image = UIImageView()
            self.UrlName = ""
            if let range = name.range(of: ".png") {
                let firstPart = name[name.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]
                self.UrlName = Constants.imageurl+firstPart+".png"
            }

            if let range = name.range(of: ".png") {
                let tagnumber = name[range.upperBound...]
                print(tagnumber)
                let url = URL(string: UrlName!)
                image.kf.setImage(with: url)
                image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
                //image.tag = Int(tagnumber)!
                image.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Int(tagnumber)!)
                imageArr.append(image)

                cell.viewMultipleImage.addSubview(image)
            }
        }


         return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are making cell object with `dequeueReusableCell`, dequeueReusable means that cell will be gonna reuse again and again. So in any situation if one cell has found `if let range = name.range(of: ".png")`, all other cell will use same images.

What you should do in this case is, remember to put `else` closes with `if` in cellForRow method.

Comment: Hello @Sharad Paghadal,

I am new with development of ios. can you please edit my code. So i can understand , what i need to do.

let me explain you one more thing here what I need to do?
1. In every cell I have One View, where I need to add multiple images as a layer. then same on the other cell. first time it's showing correct but when I scroll all the image going shuffle.

Comment: simply add `else` after `if` every where. I mean `if` shouldn't be alone.

Comment: `if let range = name.range(of: ".png") {` in this if clouse, you are assigning value to cell. just put else for reseting the value of `cell.viewMultipleImage.addSubview(image)`. it works? @VikramSurjan

Comment: I did it with else everywhere. but when I scroll then it's just shuffle my UIView part where I am adding multiple UIIMageView on runtime into the UIView.

Comment: Is there any why to use non-reusable cell ? for UITableView ?

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e this will give all your answers

Comment: This is great one to know more about UITableView and Handling about UIIamgeView under TableView. But My issue is another. My issue is : 1- I have many cell 2- evey cell have one UIView where I have to add many UIImageView into UIView.